# #ERROR validating docker-compose.yaml: services.db.volumes.0 type is required (encounterd while running "$ docker compose up -d --build")

Tags: docker, parsing, docker-compose, yaml, docker-volume

I have included the config properties below in a file labelled `docker-compose.yaml` then tried to run the respective docker compose commands to build  the respective images and spin up the corresponding two containers for web and db services on docker compose V2. I got the "services.db.volumes.0" validation error.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./services/web
    command: python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./services/web/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    env_file:
      - ./.venv.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data: /var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker_flask
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker_flask
      - POSTGRES_DB=docker_flask_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    type: named
```

I researched and narrowed down to YAML parsing. I then installed the YAML parser implemented in C++ and expected the command to run successfully, however, the validation error message was returned. I am trying to demystify the stuff about volumes on docker...

Comment: There is an extra space after `postgres_data:` which is causing it to be interpreted as a YAML dictionary rather than a `volumename:/container/path` string.

Comment: Yeah! That resolves the error. Hey @DavidMaze direct me to a great YAML reference to get my beginner self  into digging deeper into YAML syntax and understand errors